# Is it possible to read SMS in Android NOT for verification code?

Tags: android, sms

I need to get a link from auto-sent-SMS, but this SMS is always from a different number, so it's not like Retriever API.

I wanted to know - is it even possible for Android 8-9 and higher to programmatically read SMS via app?

If you know some examples on how - appreciate if you'll share :)

*most of the topics here are outdated or related to Retriever API so I wanted to know for sure about the latest Android versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [Telephony.Sms.Inbox](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Inbox) and [Telephony.Sms.Sent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Sent) content providers to access incoming and outgoing sms data. I used this far far way ago, but now i got my old code, and it still working in api 29. Here is my sample code to get basic data from inbox table,  it's full text, but better way is to access content_uri and columns via content provider classes. If you want to get more columns, check docs. Remember, you need to grant `READ_SMS` permission.

```
        Uri inboxUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "date", "date_sent", "address", "body" };
        String sortOrder = "date";
        String limit = " DESC";

        Cursor cursor = mContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().
                query(inboxUri, projection, null, null, sortOrder + limit);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    //read sms data
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
```